# SharePoint workbench full width webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, workbench

I'm currently building a SharePoint SPFx react webpart.

While developing the webpart I'm viewing/accessing the webpart using workbench using the following link: https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/Website/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx

Is there any way to make this page full width? Here is a screenshot: https://ibb.co/jkZYprP

As you can see the section to add the webpart has a `max-width` of `924px` on the `workbenchPageContent` div. This is an issue because my actualy SharePoint site is using a theme with full with layout. So when I load the webpart on my actual SharePoint site, my frontend looks different. This makes it hard to do front-end UI work since the workbench and my live site have different widths.

Answer (score 7):

You can add below css in the starting of the webpart scss file(yourwebpartname.module.scss)

```
:global {
  #workbenchPageContent,
  .CanvasComponent.LCS .CanvasZone {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: WOW! I wish I asked this question MONTHS AGO! This helped so much! Had no idea I can target classes by using `:global`

Comment: @hisusu32 If you feel the answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: This is the answer. So much better than the css machete I was using. I hope when @hisusu32 returns he will mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

You can add "supportsFullBleed": true to enable full width column for your webpart. You can find more info here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column

Comment: The important quotation from this article:
"The SharePoint workbench doesn't support testing web parts in the full-width column layout. Instead, you will have to deploy your web part to a developer tenant, create a communication site, and test your web part there."
So, it doesn't help.